# What means ls -d?

Tags: ls

When I use the `-d`, I only have the `.` that is displayed on the standard output. However, I also have other files in the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

The `-d` option says:

```
-d, --directory
       list directories themselves, not their contents
```

This is showing you `.` because that **is** your current directory.  This could be used in combination with `-l` if you simply wanted to see the permissions/ownership of the directory, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

The `-d` switch lists the directory itself and not the contents. In your case, that means the current directory. If you run `ls -ld`, it will show the permissions, ownership, last changed time, etc of the current directory.

If you run `ls -d another_directory` then it will show the same for whatever directory you specify.